# Syntax Error on PHP unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress

i can't find the error. Someone could help me?

The parser say this:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ',' or ';'

Here's the code:

```
     if(1 != $pages)
         {
             echo "<div class="pagination"><span>Pagina ".$paged." di ".$pages."</span>";
         }
```

Comment: You have to escape your double-quotes when defining your DIV-class., like this: `class=\"pagination\"`.

Comment: The problem is that you are using double quotes inside the string you wish to echo, which closes the string. Your program sees `echo "<div class=" and after that it expects a command terminator (either `,` or `;`), but instead a T_STRING (`pagination`) is following. You need to escape the quotes by using a backslash character, or use single quotes when you have quotes inside your string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're echoing all stuff in double quotes `"`, so as you doing for `class` as well, in actual, this is happening

```
echo "<div class="pagination"><span>Pagina ".$paged." di ".$pages."</span>"
```

so if you pay attention, what is happening here is: `echo "stuff class = "class" other stuff here!"`

so you're putting double quotes(DQ) `"` inside `DQ`.
to make this work, wither you'll have to escape them properly(by putting back slash `\` in front of each inner `DQ` like this

```
echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Pagina ".$paged." di ".$pages."</span>"
```

OR simply using single quote `'` for `class = 'pagination'` instead of `DQs`

```
if(1 != $pages)
     {
         echo "<div class='pagination'><span>Pagina ".$paged." di ".$pages."</span>";
     }
```

Comment: Could you please add more information on why this would help answering the question?

Comment: @Ivan He  modified "pagination" to 'pagination.

Comment: thanks man! I resolved

Answer (score 1):

Change to

```
echo "<div class=\"pagination\"><span>Pagina ".$paged." di ".$pages."</span>";
```